# checking iphone firmware over USB connection

Tags: iphone, cocoa, connection, usb

I wonder if I can write a code to check the firmware version of an iPhone connected to USB.

How can I do that in cocoa?

I wanna be more clear about my question.

I want to check the firmware version of an iphone once it is plugged into a computer's USB.

iTunes can do that, whether it is jailbroken or not. My question is not being jailbroken or not. I am talking about all iphones.

What I want basically is to control the iphone firmware version through a code.

Is that very difficult?
I am surprised since there is no answer except for a comment.

Thanks.

Comment: The code is 42. Now in all seriousness check here http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=MobileDevice_Library